# Check if leading characters in a string are letters using SQL

Tags: sql, string, validation

How would I find if the first four letters of a string contained only letters (upper or lowercase?)

I have tried

```
            DECLARE @someString VARCHAR(40) = 'B331hBlahBlahBlah'
            IF(SUBSTRING(@someString, 1, 4) LIKE '[A-Za-z]%') 
                print 'this is all text, no numbers in here'
            else
                print 'this string contains numbers'
```

but the output is 'this is all text, no numbers in here'

Thanks for any help

Comment: is this sql-server?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to repeat the pattern for each character:

```
        DECLARE @someString VARCHAR(40) = 'B331hBlahBlahBlah';

        IF @someString LIKE '[A-Za-z][A-Za-z][A-Za-z][A-Za-z]%') 
            PRINT 'this is all text, no numbers in here';
        ELSE
            PRINT 'this string contains numbers';
```

Your version is testing only the first character.  The rest match the wildcard.

Also, the `substring()` is unnecessary with the wildcard - one or the other, but both is overkill.

A more accurate rendition -- based on the `PRINT` messages -- would be:

```
        DECLARE @someString VARCHAR(40) = 'B331hBlahBlahBlah';

        IF LEFT(@someString, 4) LIKE '%[0-9]%') 
            PRINT 'this string contains numbers';
        ELSE
            PRINT 'this is all text, no numbers in here';
```